# Keras TensorFlow Probability model not learning distribution spread

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, calibration, tensorflow-probability

I built and trained a Keras Tensorflow Probability model.  It's basically a fully connected Neural Network model with a DistributionLambda on the output layer.  Last Layer code example here:

```
tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
            lambda t: tfd.Independent(tfd.Normal(loc=t[..., :n], scale=1e-5 + tf.nn.softplus(c + t[..., n:])),
                                      reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1))
```

During training I'm using Mean Squared Error as my loss function.  The training seems to progress well and is numerically stable.

After training, I start by removing the last layer of the model and then make forward-pass predictions with my test set data.  This basically gives me the "learned" expected `loc` and `scale` for the distribution the model learned for each data point in the test set.  However, because of the `softplus` correction in the `DistributionLambda` I also have to apply that same correction to the chopped model's prediction for `scale`.

I'm trying to verify that the model learned the appropriate distributions contingent on the input values.  So, with these predictions for the `loc` (mean) and `scale` (standard deviation) I can create calibration plots to see how well the model learned the latent distributions.  The calibration plot for the mean looks great.  I'm also creating a calibration plot for the `scale`/stdev parameter with code like this:

```
def create_stdev_calibration_plot(df: pd.DataFrame,
                              y_true: str = 'y_true',
                              y_pred_mean: str = 'y_pred_mean',
                              y_pred_std: str = 'y_pred_std',
                              title: Optional[str] = None,
                              save_path: Optional[str] = None):

    # Compute the residuals
    df['residual'] = df[y_true] - df[y_pred_mean]

    # Bin data based on predicted standard deviation
    bins = np.linspace(df[y_pred_std].min(), df[y_pred_std].max(), 10)
    df['bin'] = np.digitize(df[y_pred_std], bins)

    # For each bin, compute mean predicted std and actual std of residuals
    df['y_pred_variance'] = df[y_pred_std] ** 2
    bin_means_variance = df.groupby('bin')['y_pred_variance'].mean()

    # Convert back to standard deviation
    bin_means = np.sqrt(bin_means_variance)
    bin_residual_stds = df.groupby('bin')['residual'].std()

    # Create the calibration plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    plt.plot(bin_means, bin_residual_stds, 'o-')

    xrange = plt.xlim()
    yrange = plt.ylim()
    max_val = max(xrange[1], yrange[1])
    min_val = min(xrange[0], yrange[0])
    plt.axline((min_val, min_val), (max_val, max_val), linestyle='--', color='k', linewidth=2)

    plt.xlabel('Mean Predicted Standard Deviation')
    plt.ylabel('Actual Standard Deviation of Residuals')
    plt.title('Spread Calibration Plot')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

I generated some synthetic data to prove that this standard deviation calibration plot works as expected like this:

```
# Number of samples
n_samples = 1000

# Input feature
x = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, size=n_samples)

# True mean and standard deviation as functions of the input feature
true_mean = 2 * x + 3
true_std = 0.5 * np.abs(x) + 1

# Generate synthetic data
y_true = np.random.normal(loc=true_mean, scale=true_std)

# Simulate model predictions (with some error)
y_pred_mean = true_mean + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=n_samples)
y_pred_std = true_std + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.5, size=n_samples)

# Ensure standard deviations are positive
y_pred_std = np.abs(y_pred_std)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'y_true': y_true,
    'y_pred_mean': y_pred_mean,
    'y_pred_std': y_pred_std
})

create_stdev_calibration_plot(df)
```

Here's what the calibration looks like with the synthetic data:
[image]

When I run the same function on the output data from my model the plot looks like this:
[image]

Based on the calibration plot.  It *looks* like the model is NOT learning the spread, but just learning the mean and keeping the spread tight to minimize the loss.  What changes can I make to my training to incentivize the model to accurately learn the spread?

#### Update:

One thought I had was to create a custom loss function that is based off of the average [expected calibration error](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/expected_calibration_error) from both the mean and spread calibrations.  However, the inputs for loss functions are the `y_true` tensor and the `y_pred` tensor from the model.  The `y_pred` would just be samplings from the current learned distribution(s) and I wouldn't be able to know the distribution parameters (`loc` and `scale`); that makes the spread calibration impossible.  Also expected calibration error is not differentiable due to the binning required, so that makes learning with back propagation impossible as well.

#### Update 2:

I'm currently looking into changing the loss function to be the negative log likelihood (NLL).  I'll have the "learned" distribution parameters so I can just calculate the loss based on the NLL for each data point against the "learned" distributions.  I'm not confident this will work though because the NLL for only 1 data point (1 per row and distribution combination) *might* just do the same thing as MSE, since the NLL is maximized when a single data point equals the distribution mean.